# Intents in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, android-intent, android-activity

So, I know that in **Java** we use this to launch new `Activity`:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I'm writting a project using **Kotlin** and you use:

```java
val intent = Intent(this, SomeActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

But it crashes with this fatal exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pashabred.passlin, PID: 15243
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pashabred.passlin/com.pashabred.passlin.Enterring}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                            Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at com.pashabred.passlin.Enterring.onCreate(Enterring.kt:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: The exception happens at com.pashabred.passlin.Enterring.onCreate(Enterring.kt:17). What is on that line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ensure you have a `?` after Bundle:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Instead of just Bundle:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had a question mark, any other ides what can be  problem?

Comment: Oh, its no need, I dont know why but when I rewrote code it started to work) Thank you very much for help

Comment: Accept the answer then ;)

Comment: everything is same but still, I am getting errors with intent

Answer (score 41):

Intents using Kotlin for Android are almost the same. We just need to change it slightly in the syntax as below.

```
val intent = Intent(this, HelloActivity::class.java)  
startActivity(intent)
```

The exception you are getting:
Is a *null pointer exception* in your `onCreate` method on the activity...

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question

Comment: Why do we need to add `.java` in the end? Isn't HelloActivity a .kt file?

Comment: Its because you are calling Java Code from the Kotlin as Intent is a Java Class in Android which accepts .class reference as mentioned below.

Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)

Kotlin class reference is not the same as a Java class reference. To obtain a Java class reference, use the .java property on a KClass instance as SampleActivity::class returns KClass which is Kotlin class not a java class.

So you cannot pass Kotlin class reference to Java (Intent in your case) and so you have to pass Java class reference.

Answer (score 11):

The shortest and the simplest way I use to open a new activity

```
startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, NextActivity::class.java))
```

P.S: One of the main points to notice here is that the Intent() is expecting a packageContext as the first parameter hence just using **this** will still throw an error.

Hence, you need to explicitly define the class name. As shown in the above line (this@MainActivity)

Answer (score 4):

As explained on [this page](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-awesome-tricks-for-android/#crayon-5b012bc043e60755528721), Anko also provides some nice functions to navigate to other activity without the need of creating an intent, adding the extras or calling the function.

Everything can be done in a single line:

```
startActivity<DetailActivity>("id" to 2, "name" to "Kotlin")
```

This will create a set of extras for the intent with the values specified by the list of pairs the function is receiving as a parameter.

Comment: If you copy and paste a section of an article, please, reference it.
https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-awesome-tricks-for-android/

Answer (score 4):

> Intents in kotlin

```
//In Activity
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)

//for fragment change "this" to "activity"
val intent = Intent(activity, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

> Intent in kotlin single line

```
startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call like this

```
 val intent = Intent(this, ListActivity::class.java)
 startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create Singleton class for application instance for example :

   ```
   class MyApp: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: MyApp
            private set
    }
   }
   ```
2. then after call it where you required application object instance. for example :

   ```
    val intent: Intent = Intent(MyApp.instance, DestinationActivity::class.java);
    MyApp.instance.startActivity(intent)
   ```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 2):

Intents in android kotlin can be used as given below.

```
val intent = Intent(this,YourActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Further, the exception that you are getting exists in your `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 1):

You're having a null pointer exception on the `onCreate` method of the new activity. Please check the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Can you please explain the function of ? in onCreate

Answer (score 1):

You can try "context?.applicationContext" instead of "this"

```
val intent = Intent(context?.applicationContext,TimerActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Adapter Class`
specify your `context`

```
val mContext: Context
```

then

```
val intent = Intent(mContext, ActivityNext::class.java)
        mContext.startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the issue still stands or other 'Stack Overflowers' encountering something similar, ensure that your Activity file name (i.e. SomeActivity) is named accordingly or the same in 'AndroidManifest.xml' file

[image]